# Reading with scanf without delimits

Tags: c

Sample input from user:

```
A10
```

Trying to read in this input

```
scanf_s("%c%d", &playerX, &playerY, 10);
```

Does input from the user need to be delimited? Is it possible to read in like this?

Edit: I have tested this and it just crashes.

Edit 2: Solution: scanf_s("%c%d", &playerX, 1, &playerY);

Comment: `scanf_s("%c%d", &playerX, 1, &playerY);`

Comment: What is this `10` there?

Comment: If you read e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that "All conversion specifiers other than [, c, and n consume and discard all leading whitespace characters before attempting to parse the input". That means that no delimite is needes, but `scanf` automatically handles whitespace (space, newline, tab etc.) as a "delimiter".

Comment: BLUEPIXY code worked.

Comment: And it works because [Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or [. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the information! Does it discard extra characters?

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `scanf_s` is tricky:

```
char playerX;
int playerY;

if (scanf_s("%c%d", &playerX, (size_t)1, &playerY) == 2) {
    /* input parsed correctly */
    /* input stopped after the last digit in playerY */
    /* You cannot limit the number of digits this way */
} else {
    /* end of file or missing number */
    /* input stopped before the offending character */
}
```

`scanf_s` is a poor fix for `scanf`'s very many shortcomings.  The array size must be passed after each pointer argument for `c`, `s` and `[` formats.  But this size must be passed as an `rsize_t`, which is the same as a `size_t` with a restriction on the maximum value.  Passing `1` is plain wrong as `1` is an `int` and `scanf_s` takes a variable number of arguments, thus does not convert extra arguments automatically.  If will fail in mysterious ways on architectures where `int` and `size_t` differ in size, such as 64 bit windows, linux and OS/X.

You can avoid subtle problems like this by increasing the warning level of the compiler. `gcc -Wall -Werror` or `clang -Wall -Werror` are a good start.  Never ignore these helpful warnings, if you don't understand them, you probably do not know what your code really does.

Unless `scanf_s` is mandated by your coding rules or your compiler, it is simpler to use `scanf` and just as safe for this format:

```
if (scanf("%c%d", &playerX, &playerY) == 2) ...
```

Comment: LSNED: `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(rsize_t)`. +1

Comment: @chux: Thank you for a self referring acronym: today I learned that LSNED means *Learn Something New EveryDay*. One of my favorite mottos.

Comment: One of the issues of C11's Ann. K is that many of those functions including `scanf_s()` are different from their MS counterparts. MS's implementation of `scanf_s()` expects `unsigned int` and not `rsize_t`.

Comment: @cremno: LSNED for me. This does not surprise me, `int` would be more consistent with other `printf` idioms for width and precision and should be passed before the pointer, not after.  This discrepancy makes `scanf_s` definitively useless.  The OP can easily solve his problem with `scanf` and it would actually be better for him to write lower-level code using `getc()` tailored to his needs, as he is concerned with discarded characters. `scanf` has too many quirks anyway.